# Connection timeout scala JsoupBrowser

Tags: scala, parsing, web-crawler

Is there a way how to set connection timeout for JsoupBrowser in scala? It is library https://github.com/ruippeixotog/scala-scraper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a sub-class by extending the JsoupBrowser base class and override it's default request settings in order to customize them.

```
import net.ruippeixotog.scalascraper.browser.JsoupBrowser
import org.jsoup.Connection
import scala.concurrent.duration.Duration
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

object Test extends App {

  class CustomJsoupBrowser(timeout: Int) extends JsoupBrowser {
    override protected[this] def defaultRequestSettings(conn: Connection): Connection = {
      super.defaultRequestSettings(conn)
      conn.timeout(timeout)
    }
  }

  val browser = new CustomJsoupBrowser(Duration(10L, TimeUnit.SECONDS).toMillis.toInt)
  val doc = browser.get("http://www.wikipedia.org")
  println(doc)
}
```